# Inheritance between related classes

Tags: c#, object, inheritance

I need to tidy up a system that creates a bunch of Programs. Each Program is defined in the following way:

- A program contains multiple modules
- A module contains multiple parameters

The C# looks like this for the Program:

```
public class Program : IProgram
{
    /// <summary>Program name</summary>
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Program name</summary>
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Holds all the modules and its parameters</summary>
    public Modules Modules { get; private set; } = new Modules();

    public void Initialize(JToken programToken)
    {
        JToken modulesToken = programToken["MODULES"];

        // Clear Modules
        Modules.Clear();

        foreach (var moduleToken in modulesToken)
        {
            IModule module = CreateModuleFromName((string)moduleToken["API"]);
            if (module != null)
            {
                module.Initialize(moduleToken);
                Modules.Add(module);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for the Modules:

```
public class Modules : List<IModule>
{
    public IModule this[string moduleName] => this.First(m => m.ModuleName== moduleName);
}

public class SomeModule : BaseModule
{
    [DataMember]
    public const string ModuleName= "SOME_MODULE";

    [DataMember]
    public const string EnableString = "Enable";

    /// <summary>
    /// Field representing the if this module is enabled
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public IParameter Enable
    {
        get => Parameters.GetParameter(EnableString);
        set => Parameters.Set(value);
    }
}
```

I won't bore you with the Parameter class, which follows the same logic.

Now, the programs, modules and parameters get populated based on some Json file. The thing that bugs me here is that there is no inheritance between Programs -> Modules -> Parameters.
The coder decided to have the Program class parsing the Json at initialisation and then dynamically populate a list of modules.
Is this the correct approach? My limited understanding of the object world would think it is a bad approach (but maybe he had no choice in order to compose the List of Modules dynamically). If so, how would you correct it?

Please also note that Program, Module and Parameter classes are all independent assemblies. Which is also something I don't quite get. Should they not all be part of the same one?

Comment: As a suggestion, there is a sister site to Stackoverflow specifically for code review, which I believe this post would fit best under... But having inheritance between a `program` and `module`  sounds like it violates basic principals of separation of concerns. Your model seems logical... I probably wouldn't have the `program` type do any serialization, factories should be built to construct the types.

Comment: This is using composition which is correct here.  Inheritance is for when one object is a more specific version of another.  Program, Module and Parameter are related, but none are more specific types of the other.

Comment: Why should there be inheritance? A Program _Has_ Modules. But it's not that a Module _Is-A_ Program. The "different assemblies" part is odd, but may have made sense at some point in time.

Comment: As far as your last comment. If they're a good developer, the allocation of types to different assemblies insinuates that there is DI and could be part of the design...

Comment: @Trae Moore: Would you mind pointing me out to this sister site? So you mean I should get the Json parser out of the Program class? And maybe feed the Json parser's output to it instead?

Comment: @stackMeUp -  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Absolutely, parsing Json should be part of your serialization/web utilities, dependant upon your architecture of course.

Comment: So you guys would rather have all these classes under the same Project, with different namespaces, generating a single assembly, but keep the same workflow?

Comment: That will completely depend on the design, requirements and layers of the app.

Comment: That is not very helpful :-)

Comment: @stackMeUp - lol, I know... and I'm sorry, but without an understanding of your application architecture, how big the application is and what technology it will integrate with, that's the best answer I can give. Other than saying, logically separate your dependencies... think about how you will scale and maintain your application...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the correct approach?

Yes.  Use derivation to model the "is a kind of" relationship.  Use composition to model the "contains a bunch of" relationship.  Chess is a kind of game, so class Chess should derive from base class Game. A game of chess *has a bunch of pieces*, and pieces are not *a kind of game*, so pieces should not derive from Game. Rather, class Chess should be *composed* of pieces.

A program is not *a kind of* module and a module is not *a kind of* program, so there should be no derivation relationship. Rather, you said that a program *consists of multiple modules*; that should be modeled using composition, not derivation.

> Please also note that Program, Module and Parameter classes are all independent assemblies. Which is also something I don't quite get. Should they not all be part of the same one?

That seems suspicious, but not *necessarily* wrong.  An assembly is by definition *the smallest unit of shippable, independently versioned code*. Does it make sense to ship a new kind of module *without* shipping a new kind of program? If it does, then they should be in different assemblies. If not, then they should be in the same assembly.

Comment: Great answer, very much appreciated!